# writing large amounts of data to exec.Command().StdinPipe() errors

Tags: go

Consider the following Go code fragment:

```
cmd := exec.Command(program, arg0)
stdin, err := cmd.StdinPipe()
// produces error when b is too large
n, err := stdin.Write(b.Bytes())
```

Whenever `b` is too large, `Write()` returns an error.  Having experimented with different size `b`s, it would seem this occurs whenever the length of `b` is longer than the Linux pipe buffer size.  Is there a way around this?  Essentially I need to feed large log files via stdin to an external script.

Comment: Please show the error returned from Write.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote this program to test your code:

```
package main

import "os/exec"
import "fmt"


func main() {
        cmd := exec.Command("/bin/cat")

        in, _ := cmd.StdinPipe()

        cmd.Start()

        for i := 1024*1024; ; i += 1024*1024 {
                b := make([]byte,i)
                n, err := in.Write(b)
                fmt.Printf("%d: %v\n", n, err)
                if err != nil {
                        cmd.Process.Kill()
                        return
                }
        }
}
```

The only way this program gives an error is if the called process closes stdin. Does the program you call close stdin? This might be a bug in the Go runtime.

Comment: what platform are you running on?

Comment: @Woot4Moo I'm using Linux.

Comment: i guess to be more precise, which linux variant.

Comment: Linux 3.8.0, Ubuntu 13.04